# ToolTip Parent Fading On .fadeOut - Not Meant To

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, parent

I am somewhat new to Javascipt/Jquery (I've known about it for a long time, but only really started messing around).

I am trying to write a simple tooltip function for the following markup:

```
<ul class="exec-List">
    <li class="give-tooltip">
        <img src="test.png" /> 

            <span title="Loloscoped" class="tooltip-span">Content</span>

    </li>
    <li>
         <img src="test.png" /> 

            <span title="Loloscoped" class="tooltip-span">Content</span>

   </li>
</ul>
```

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
function simple_tooltip( target_items, target_class, give_class )
{

$( target_items ).each(function( i )
{       

    var current_item = $(this);

    if( current_item.hasClass( 'give-tooltip' ) )
    {
        alert( 'has tooltip class' );   

        var current_child = current_item.children(this);

        if( current_child.hasClass( 'tooltip-span' ))
        {
            current_item.mouseenter(function()
            {
                current_child.fadeIn( 400 );
            });
            current_item.mouseleave(function()
            {
                current_child.fadeOut( 400 );
            });
        }
    }

});

}
```

The problem is, the selector for what to fadeIn and fadeOut is targeting the entire item, and not the span of class "tooltip-span". I believe this to be the case because when the mouse leaves the `<li>` element, the entire `<li>` fades away. When the mouse enters the `<span>` is revealed, but I believe if the `<li>` was hidden as well it would also fade in.

What am I doing wrong in trying to select the child?

I would be using:

```
display: none;
```

And in another class:

```
display: block !important;
```

In the CSS, but I require a fade time, which you cannot achieve with the `display` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still couldn't solve it so I changed my JS to work from the child to the parent, and not from the parent to the child.

Here is code that works:

```
function tooltip( target_tag, parent_class, tooltip_class )
{

$( target_tag ).each(function()
{
        var current_item = $(this);
        var current_parent = current_item.parent(this);
        if( ( current_parent.get(0).tagName == 'LI' ) && ( current_parent.hasClass( parent_class ) ) )
        {
            current_parent.mouseenter(function()
            {
                current_item.fadeIn( 400 );
            }).mouseleave(function()
            {
                current_item.fadeOut( 400 );
            });
        }
});

}


$(document).ready(function()
{
     tooltip( "span", "give-tooltip", "tooltip-span" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to show the span with class **tooltip-span** on hover of the parent li with class **give-tooltip**

If I am understanding correct you can replace your code with the following

```
$('li.give-tooltip').hover(
   function(){
               $(this).find('span.tooltip-span').fadeIn(400);
             },
   function(){
               $(this).find('span.tooltip-span').fadeOut(400);
             }
);
```